# Getting a notification when a button is pressed on the iPhone when the screen is off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, events, button

I'm planning to create a life saving application, and I need to integrate with any of the physical buttons on the iPhone (Home, volume, lock). 
Is this possible programmatically when the screen is off (on a non jail-broken device)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm curious if you ever got it to work. I'm developing a similar one.

Comment: As I understood from the comments here that this was not possible, I abandoned the idea. However,  almost 3 years have passed so I'm not sure what's the latest on this.

Comment: I can say it is physically possible on iOS. I just got it working yesterday. Android allows this. Apple will likely reject it at first. My plan B is a grass roots effort to demand it. This could help so many people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your idea, but I don't think that this will be obtainable on a non-jailbroken device. @Andrews answer could work if your app was triggered by a combination of play/pause, next and back but would require that your app was always the responder to the devices audio controls which is only possible between the time when the user closes your app, and launches anything else that takes control of device audio. (which probably wouldn't be that long)

Assuming that this would be the iOS version of Life Alert, that would dial emergency services for the user, it would be too difficult to keep the app from generating false positives and calling 911 every time the phone had a few buttons pressed in a pocket, purse, etc. Whereas with a jailbreak it may be possible to listen to a pattern (eg. home button- press, press, hold, press, press)

On top of this attempting to use anything on the lock screen for something other than its intended purpose will most likely result in rejection by Apple. They're big on user experience, and would want your application in anyway interfering with any of functionality of the device.

Once again, I think you have a good idea, but I'm sorry to say that it just may not be possible to do on iOS. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the hardware buttons for anything other than their usage or Apple will reject your app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get that directly, but there are a couple of ways to get it in a roundabout fashion.

As an example, 
If you create a [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) object you can register for MPMusicPlayerControllerVolumeDidChangeNotification and you will be notified when the volume changes. Volume changes can come from pressing the hardware volume buttons, but there are other conditions which could trigger them.

Comment: Would an implementation of this kind pass Apple's verification system?

Answer (score 0):

Not likely. Apple locks that stuff down pretty good.